# Построение диаграмм Python

Tags: python, list

Читал статьи по этому поводу, но нигде не нашел варианта, как можно построить диаграмму из подобного списка:

```
l = [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

Чтобы не нужно было создавать отдельный список с количеством единиц и двоек, чтобы это было более кратко или автоматически.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Countplot? https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html

Comment: не нашел, потому что не искал.

Answer (score 3):

```
import seaborn as sns

lst = [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2] 
sns.countplot(x=lst)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]